# Alarm everyday at 5AM morning

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

I am working on an android application where I need to trigger an alarm every morning at 5 am. I have already used the concept of `Intent`(below is the code) and putting `AlarmManager` in the `Service`. But I didnt get the problem solution from both implementations. I am just looking for a perfect solution for this. If I add a reminder to the `calendar` for 1 month once the application is opened for the first time I guess that might work. But if there is any better solution for this, then please provide. It should trigger an alarm at 5 AM every day no matter what. How can I achieve this?

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You may need "Service" in background

Comment: Can you provide example @ashishdhiman2007

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set app to trigger service/alarm at a specific time every day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273528/how-to-set-app-to-trigger-service-alarm-at-a-specific-time-every-day)

Comment: @Haem tried that. But no solution.

Comment: can you specify device and os version of your device ?

Comment: ASUS ZenPad 8.0 and Marshamallow @jiteshmohite

Comment: so the only issue is time? not alarm?

Comment: Yes the time. Notification is coming. Alarm is getting triggered. But wrong time its coming. @jiteshmohite

Comment: So when you tried this, what happened? Did the alarm play only once or it didn't play at all or it played some time and didn't play the rest of the time?

Comment: currently I kept a notification for testing. Notification is coming, but its not coming in the right time. Its coming anytime(not at 5am) mostly around 8am or 11am. @Aradhna

Comment: try setting your alarm as "Exact" instead of "inexact", also `Calendar` takes hours in 24 hour format so you don't need to specify AM/PM.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the following things

1. change the alarm type from `inexactrepeating` to `repeating`
2. change `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` to `calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);`

let me know if this works.

Comment: looks like somewhere you are missing some permissions and that's why this is not working out. Paste your whole code so that we can have a better look.

Answer (score -2):

you need to implement services:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Moreover, you may find many tutorials on implementing services in app

Comment: I have already tried setting AlarmManager inside a PendingService but that also didn't work.

Comment: have you registered your service in android manifest? or in activity?

Comment: Yes I did.. and I am getting the notification as well. But not in the current time which I am setting.

Comment: @XoXo check time zones , I guess it is because of that, debug the time you are setting for alarm and convert it to your device's time zone and verify hope it helps